# java catch a NumberFormatException on a Numeric type

Tags: java, exception, numbers, format, try-catch

Hi I have created a quiz application using java but I am unsure how to implement this small section. It asks me to : 
**Add an exception to catch a NumberFormatException on a NumericQuestion type if the user enters a character i.e. ‘a’**

I initially tried inserting a try catch block at the beginning of the presentQuestion method but it threw me a lot of errors. I don't have much experience in implementing these try-catch methods. I know its probably something simple so any help would be appreciated cheers.
My code is show below.

```
package QuestionGame;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumericQuestionTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean userCorrect;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        NumericQuestion quThree = new NumericQuestion("What is the answer to 5 divided by 3?", "1.67", 2, 0.03, 0.07);
        presentQuestion(input, quThree);
        input.close();

    }

    public static void presentQuestion(Scanner input, NumericQuestion q) {
        boolean userCorrect;
        q.displayQuestion();
        System.out.println("Enter your answer: ");
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        userCorrect = q.checkAnswer(answer);
        if (userCorrect){
            System.out.println("Correct! The answer is : " + q.getAnswer() + " and you have a score of : " + q.getMark());
        } else {
            System.out.println(answer + " is incorrect. You scored zero.");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


package QuestionGame;

public class NumericQuestion extends Question {

    //instance variables
    private double ansNumeric;
    private double positiveRange;
    private double negativeRange;

    //constructor
    public NumericQuestion(String quText, String answer, int mark, double positiveRange, double negativeRange) {
        super(quText, answer, mark);
        this.ansNumeric = Double.parseDouble(answer);
        this.positiveRange = positiveRange;
        this.negativeRange = negativeRange;
    }

    //accessors & mutators
    public double getAnsNumeric() {
        return ansNumeric;
    }

    public void setAnsNumeric(double ansNumeric) {
        this.ansNumeric = ansNumeric;
    }

    //methods

    public boolean checkAnswer (String answer) {
        double answerDouble = Double.parseDouble(answer);
        if (answerDouble > (this.ansNumeric + this.positiveRange)) {
            return false;
        } else if (answerDouble < (this.ansNumeric - this.negativeRange)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: use try/catch block?

Comment: Just go through [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm) to understand exception handling in java. Then look at your problem.

Comment: Does `checkAnswer` go with `String` argument?

Comment: show please code of `checkAnswer`

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam, why should the OP make use of other sites besides the plain old [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)?

Comment: @aribeiro There are multiple resources in the internet. I gave a link which i prefer, There is no rule that one should only use documents from oracle.

Comment: Hi I have edited my post to show the numericQuestion class which shows the check answer method I have implemented.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam, I'm totally in agree with you. But on this case, as a learning starting point, Java doc should be the ideal.

Comment: can you provide error log?

Comment: edited my answer, I put exception handling, and retry logic together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, depending on the application design. I'll show you one here - please provide more details if this does not apply, though I guess this is what you are looking for

```
public static void presentQuestion(Scanner input, NumericQuestion q) {
        boolean userCorrect = false;
        boolean isAnswerNumeric = false;
        String answer = null;
        while(! isAnswerNumeric){
            q.displayQuestion();
            System.out.println("Enter your answer (numeric only) : ");
            answer = input.nextLine();
            try{
                Double.parseDouble(answer);
                isAnswerNumeric = true;
            }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
               // do nothing in this case.. if the number format is correct, 
               // the isAnswerNumeric will be set to true
            }
        }
        userCorrect = q.checkAnswer(answer);
        if (userCorrect){
            System.out.println("Correct! The answer is : " + q.getAnswer() + " and you have a score of : " + q.getMark());
        } else {
            System.out.println(answer + " is incorrect. You scored zero.");
        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

You can adapt the code to display an error message or whatever you want to do in the catch block. In this case, as a simple example, the question is asked again until the answer is numeric

Comment: the String variable answer is out of range after the while loop ends just before this line of code:  userCorrect = q.checkAnswer(answer);

 any ideas on how to resolve that?

Comment: simply moved the declaration of the variable in the upper scope. The variable is set to a numeric value in the loop :)

Comment: thanks for that! working fine. does NumberFormatException e do the same thing as NumberFormatException nfe?

Comment: @niilzon, have you stolen my answer or we just think in the same direction?

Comment: @Liam : this is the name of the exception that you catch, so you can call it "e" if you wish. I call exceptions like IOExceptions "ioe" and FileNotFoundException "fnfe" and Exceptions "e" but this is just a personal reading convention (that I recommend :) )

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ lol I guess we somewhat think in the same direction :) I saw that when I posted my initial answer yours appeared in the meantime. Did this while talking to colleagues. Gave you an upvote since the rough logic is the same and satisfies the OP :)

Answer (score 3):

Apart `exception` handling, I suggest you add persistent check while user will not put expected integer answer.

```
do{
     System.out.println("You Numeric answer, please")
     String answer = input.nextLine();
}while !answerIsNumeric(answer);
userCorrect = q.checkAnswer(answer);

public boolean answerIsNumeric(String answer){
     try{
         Double.parseDouble(answer);
     }catch(NumberFormatException e){
         return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: The question asks me to add an exception to CATCH not by using an if statement

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to parse your `answer` String into a number with `Float.parseFloat` and catch the `NumberFormatException`.

Example:

```
    String answer = "3.14";

    try {

        float numericAnswer = Float.parseFloat(answer);

        System.out.println("numericAnswer=" + numericAnswer);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        System.err.println(answer + " is not a number.");
    }
```

And if by *Add an exception to catch a NumberFormatException* - which does not make much sense as a sentence - they mean *throw* an exception, just add in the catch block

`throw new WhateverException(answer + " is not a number.");` (f.ex. you could throw a `RuntimeException`).